# Getting full path for Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How can I find out the folder where the windows service .exe file is installed dynamically?

```
Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

returns a path based on `C:\WINDOWS\system32` directory.

However, the `XmlDocument.Load(string filename)` method appears to be working against relative path inside the directory where the service .exe file is installed to.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Comment: "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()" is null for my service.

Comment: Look at Curtis Yallop answser. Much better!

Comment: It returns the path with the executable name

Comment: Use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory - it does not involve reflection.

Answer (score 71):

Try this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

(Just like here: [How to find windows service exe path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833959/how-to-find-windows-service-exe-path))

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had an NServiceBus service, and since it gets wrapped up in NServiceBus.Host.exe, the `GetEntryAssembly()` was null in my actual project.  This one worked perfectly though.

Answer (score 39):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for our windows service:

```
//CommandLine without the first and last two characters
//Path.GetDirectory seems to have some difficulties with these (special chars maybe?)
string cmdLine = Environment.CommandLine.Remove(Environment.CommandLine.Length - 2, 2).Remove(0, 1);
string workDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(cmdLine);
```

This should give you the absolute path of the executable.

Answer (score 5):

Another version of the above:

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
string dir = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
```

Answer (score 3):

Environment.CurrentDirectory returns current directory where program is running. In case of windows service, returns %WINDIR%/system32 path that is where executable will run rather than where executable deployed.

Answer (score -4):

This should give you the path that the executable resides in:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

If not, you could try:

```
Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).FullName
```

A more hacky, but functional way:

```
Path.GetFullPath("a").TrimEnd('a')
```

:)

Comment: -1: Environment.CurrentDirectory and your hacky solution both return the current working directory, which from what the OP says is the system32 directory.