# windows service is still running but the task is not executed continuously

Tags: c#, windows, service, printing, silent

```
 public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\Log.txt", ex.ToString());
        }



    }
    public static void Print()
    {
        //Print & Move the files after printing
        DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold");
        DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold1");

        foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (fi.Length != 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
                process.StartInfo.FileName = fi.FullName;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process.Start();

                if (!process.WaitForExit(10000))
                    process.Kill();
            }

            MoveFile(fi.FullName);
        }
    }

    public static void MoveFile(string Filename)
    {
        string SourcePath = @"C:\fold";
        string targetpath = @"C:\fold1";


        if (!Directory.Exists(targetpath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetpath);
        }

        string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath);

        foreach (string sourcefile in sourceFiles)
        {
            string mfilename = Path.GetFullPath(sourcefile);
            string mname = Path.GetFileName(sourcefile);

            if (mfilename == Filename)
            {
                string distnition = Path.Combine(targetpath, mname);
                File.Move(mfilename, distnition);
            }
        }

    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    { try
        {
            //Move the files after printing
            DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold");
            DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold1");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
            {
                // File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\stop.txt", "Stop method");
                MoveFile(fi.FullName);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\fold1\Log.txt", ex.ToString());
        }


    }
```

I created a service that silently prints files in a given directory and then move them to another one , it worked fine when I started it on the first try but it doesn't run constantly , I want it to print and move any file that is copied into that directory , so what do I have to do?
please note that I'm still a begginner in c# and that I cannot quite understand if your explanation it's too complicated , thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows service stops automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538925/windows-service-stops-automatically)

Comment: The above linked to article specifically addresses a try/catch in OnStart, but you should have this in your other methods also.  Any number of errors could be cause the service to stop/crash.  You probably also want to add some logging with a logging framework like NLog, Serilog, or Log4NET so you know what's actually happening when it quits.

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your `OnStart()` method already does the concrete job and *never* returns. But the Service Manager is designed, that it waits max 60 secs till the `OnStart()` method returns, otherwise the process will be killed.

So, instead of directly calling within your `OnStart()` method your code, you should instantiate a new Task or Thread that will do the work and immediately exit the `OnStart()` method. Within the `OnStop()` method you have to inform your parallel running code to stop (e.g. by using a `CancellationToken`) and wait till it's done and then exit.

### Example

```
public partial class ServiceExample : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Task Runner;
    private CancellationTokenSource Cts;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (Cts != null) // Could also simply return
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Service is already running!");

        Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Runner = DoSomething(Cts.Token);
    }

    private async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Immediately return to caller to avoid "hanging" OnStart()
        await Task.Yield();

        // Regulary check if OnStop() is waiting for us
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Call your method that should do something.
            // If it runs longer and can be intercepted,
            // forward the CancellationToken to it.
            await Worker(cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (Cts == null) // Could also simply return
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Service already being stopped!");

        Cts.Cancel();
        Runner.Wait();
    }

    private async Task Worker(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow}: Do some heavy work!");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply @Oliver , I tried to use your code but It's not working maybe I got it wrong , where should I put my task? in this case , my task is a method called print() , I want that method to run constantly , please note that I'm a begginner at C# so I'm not quite sure of what I'm doing wrong in this case , thank you

Comment: Slightly updated the code example. You should replace the `Worker()` method with your method and use [this helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470256/process-waitforexit-asynchronously) to forward the `CancellationToken` to the long running `WaitForExit()` method.